# Proper way to convert (many!) numbers to strings without allocations in Qt

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qstring, itoa

## tl;dr

#### I want to call `QString::number(int)` many times per second. It is very slow: seems like it allocates a new string each time. Tried to use `setNum` on same string instead, still no joy.

---

<sup>Original, long question:</sup>

### The problem

I have a big array of numbers (say, integers) and I want to format them into text, that will be then (maybe not immediately) written to file. Naive way looks approximately<sup>1</sup> like this:

```
QString allData;
foreach(const int & value, values) {
    allData += QString::number(value);
    allData += '\n';
}
```

It takes about **280ms** for **150000** integers on my machine which seems to much for me. I suppose that this is because [`QString::number`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#number) is called 150000 times and each time allocates new string. This is someway confirmed to be the root of the problem when I try to use [`itoa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0we9x30h.aspx) (which does not allocate memory) instead.

### Possible, but not-Qt `[not-cute]` solution

```
QString allData;
char buffer[100];                               // <-------
foreach(const int & value, values) {
    _itoa_s(value, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 10); // <-------
    allData += buffer;
    allData += '\n';
}
```

This takes about **70ms** for the same **150000** integers (about **4x** faster) which is by now acceptable for me *(I think I can do something with string concatenation as well, but let's leave this outside this question)*

**But** I don't like that I have to use some unstandard, probably deprecated, probably unportable<sup>2</sup> function (not to say that this just looks ugly).

Then I remembered that there is also an *instance* method: [`QString::setNum`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#setNum). I hoped I could use the same pattern as with `itoa`: have only one string allocated and modify it each time.

### Desirable, but *not working* solution

```
QString allData;
QString number;                       // <-------
foreach(const int & value, values) {
    number.setNum(value);             // <-------
    allData += number;
    allData += '\n';
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't make big difference from `QString::number`: again about 280ms, well, maybe **250ms** but still too much.

So, congrats if you reached here :) and finally...

## The Question(s)

1. **What** would Qt experts advise me **to do**? Shut up and use `itoa` despite the distinct smell of C in otherwise fragrant C++/Qt code?
2. Or can I somehow say **"C'mon, Qstring, just eat this number into you"** ?
3. I wonder **why `setNum` did not do the trick**?

---

Footnotes:

<sup>1</sup> In actual code i have not just 150000 integers, but 50000 triples of integers which I also add `'\t'` between them. This is the only difference from my actual code and I guess it is not important: here I'm interested only in performance of `QString::number` vs `itoa`.

<sup>2</sup> Actually, I was surprised that MinGW also has `_itoa_s` that behaves just like as Visual Studio's, but I still have some awkward feeling that using such a dirty function in my polished Qt code reduces its portability. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I vote for 2). If you are using Qt and QString, I would not complain about performance since it is inherently a slower framework than a performance-optimized one, at least most of the time. I would never use Qt in performance critical systems. As for setNum, have you tried reserve?

Comment: @LaszloPapp, as I hoped, herer it actually appeared that not Qt is slow, but I used wrong class for this task: should be using `QByteArray` instead of `QString` (thanks to @SalvatoreAvanzo). As to your advice: I tried playing with `reserve`, but it didn't have any impact. Seems like the implementation of `QString`'s `setNum` is just slower than `QByteArray`'s one. Probably because QByteArray is just kinda wrapper over `char*`, while `QString` is much more complicated (encodings, etc).

Comment: well, you were asking about QString, so people like me assumed you insert other non-numbers, in which case QByteArray is kind of moot. The thing still stands, I really would not personally use Qt for performance critical things, especially if you are after miliseconds. It just feels bad idea to me.

Comment: Have you done a `QString::reserve()` prior to adding all those numbers? You know you'll need at least two characters per number, at most 10 (?), and you probably have a reasonable estimate how many digits you have on average.

Comment: @MSalters yes, of course :) But I insist: problem was not with not-enough-bytes initially allocated. I added some notes to @SalvatoreAvanzo's answer to explain what was the problem with `QString::setNum`.

Comment: If you need speed, then creating a custom helper function, which first uses `QString::resize()` (if necessary), then does the integer to text conversion, writing unicode characters directly to QString with `myqstr[index] = QChar(0x0030 + digitvalue);` would probably be fastest (U+0030 is Unicode code point for '0'). This is basically micro-optimization, but it allows taking shortcuts not possible in general purpose library code, and enables better optimizations (esp. inlining).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with QByteArray that shares same QString's interface but is more suitable for performance issues.I obtain 36 ms (qt 5.2 clang) vs. your original 57 ms (on my machine) with this code:

```
QByteArray allDatab;
foreach(const int & value, values) {
    allDatab += QByteArray::number(value);
    allDatab += '\n';
}
QString result(allDatab);
```

and 29 ms with this version (that maybe confirm your assumptions about setNum):

```
QByteArray allDatad;
QByteArray number;                       
foreach(const int & value, values) {
    number.setNum(value);             
    allDatad += number;
    allDatad += '\n';
}
```

Comment: Whoa, didn't even except that `QByteArray` bursts so much! O_o On my machine I got 57 ms with the second variant, so it is even faster that `QString+itoa`. Great, solves my problem.

Comment: Keep that in mind, this would not work so well if you had to insert other things before and/or after that is QString'ish. Hopefully, that is not your use case.

Comment: @LaszloPapp , important comment, thanks. In my case it was enough to convert QByteArray to QString as soon as I finished adding numbers, and only then prepend header, etc: all subsequent manipulation of this string are little, so they didn't have impact on performance.

Comment: Well, a complete answer would explain why it was slow, which is that QString is more than just a byte array. It deals with utf, locale, and all that.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Qt is a well documented framework. [There](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html) you can find an explanation of the differences between QString and QByteArray better than I do. However I will be happy if you would edit my post to add some insights to this solution.

Comment: @SalvatoreAvanzo , well, I tried to suggest edit with more info to your answer but it did not work for some reason. You can read it here: [(link)](https://gist.github.com/NIA/25560a3580e3872557a9). If you wish, you can edit your answer yourself (using [source of this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/NIA/25560a3580e3872557a9/raw/gistfile1.md)).

Answer (score 3):

How about using STL?

I tested your code (modifying the loop to simplify)

```
int main() {
  stringstream ss;
  for(int i=0; i<2000000; ++i) {
     ss << i << "\n";
  }
}
```

And I obtain

```
time ./ss_test
  real  0m0.146s
  user  0m0.139s
  sys   0m0.006s
```

With Qt version (in my machine)

```
int main() {
  QString allData;
  for(int i=0; i<2000000; ++i) {
    allData += QString::number(i);
    allData += '\n';
  }
}
```

I obtain

```
time ./qtstring_test 
   real 0m0.516s
   user 0m0.508s
   sys  0m0.008s
```

Comment: Thank you for you idea! While @SalvatoreAvanzo's solution with QByteArray has better overall performance in my situation (probably because it doesn't require inter-framework conversions), but still good idea that I may use somewhere else.